# How to package robot framework project in eclipse into an independent executable file

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, executable, packaging

I need to convert my robot framework project in eclipse to an independent executable package file?

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that? As written your question is way too vague and broad.

Comment: I need to find a way to do that. Please help if you have any solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

I saw something similar in this tutorial on Azure Devops. The author created some RF tests and made it run in a python package. Hope that can be useful for you

Article: https://medium.com/@milannovovic/robot-framework-ci-cd-with-azure-devops-cf708a64b389

Github: https://github.com/Kikkomanq/Auto1/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml